# What syntax should I use in my SQL query in the select statement in ArcMap if I want to use two In-Line substitution variables

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, sql, select

[image]I am trying to iterate though features in a shapefile. There are two columns I need to iterate through. First, I need to iterate through company names, and then using another iterator in a separate model, extract each companies subdivision. Not all companies have the same amount of subdivisions.

There are 11 companies and 75 subdivisions. I want to end up with each company's subdivision saved with the file name structure of something similar to Company_Subdivision.shp. Each feature (column) has iterator with an inline substitution variable.

I was able to rename the variables so they have a different name. The problem lies within the second select statement where I am trying to pull in both in line variables. I can only seem to use one at a time in the Select statement (even if I write it in manually).

I found this link below but I didn't see any syntax for in-line variables, let alone the syntax for using two in-line variables in the same select statement. Does anyone know how to use to in-line variables in a single select statement?

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s50000002t000000

Update: I included a screen shot of the two models and the select statement is open on the second model. The select statement is

Company = %Value% and Subdivision = %Subdivision%.

I then want to save the file and try to use both in-line variables in the output file location. I am unsure if this is even possible

Comment: Can you share the select statements that you have tried?  Please include them by editing the question.

Comment: Also, have you referenced this page? [http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/examples-of-inline-model-variable-substitution.htm](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/examples-of-inline-model-variable-substitution.htm)

Comment: Yeah it is how I eventually found the other link. My model called 'Best_Guess1' in the example is basically example number 2 in the link you provided. I basically need to do that twice using two in line variables